# Atom IDE Package

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, atom-editor

I'm trying out the Atom editor from Github and I really like it. I would like to create a simple (just to learn) plugin. I used the online resources to create the figgle example successfully.

Now I would like to create something with an UI. I would like to add an input field to my UI, but how can I get it to be styled to same way Atom does.

I see in the documentation that I have to create an element with 'atom-text-editor' tag. However this creates an text area with line numbers etc. I just want a single lined input field.

So concrete, my question is: 'How can I create an input field which looks the same as the atom one.' 
[image]

Comment: I enjoy atom as well and I was thinking of creating my own plugin as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer through atom slack chat.

```
var elem = document.createElement 'atom-text-editor'
element.setAttribute 'mini', ''
element.setAttribute 'placeholder-text', 'Search'
```

Which gives:

[image]